# Sanity of Headers

Tags: c++, linker, typechecking

I'm just starting to teach C++, coming from some other languages. I am wishing there were some way to consistently check the API created by a (student) file.

Suppose a student submits this file:

```
// this is stu.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double x(int y) {return y+0.5;}
```

Actually, suppose I asked the student to define some other function int x(int). I would like to be able to check this by running this code:

```
// this is stu.h
int x(int);

// this is gra.cpp 
#include "stu.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << x(0); // test their code
}
```

So I am trying to see if the student's implementation matched the required interface, and testing it on input 0. I would have hoped this would not compile. But when I do

```
g++ -Wall -Wconversion *.cpp -o gra
./gra
```

It compiles and runs without crashing, giving output 0. This remains true even if I compile the two files separately and link them after.

I know that `nm` doesn't list return types. Is that the same reason that we can link together two files when the return values don't match? Is there any sane way to test this? (Like are there compile-time typeof assertions?)

Or is this a specific bug because of int and double being interconvertible? Are there additionall compiler options that could catch this?

Comment: You'd get an error if `stu.cpp` included `stu.h`.

Comment: Yup, you should compile with `-Wall -Werror -Wextra`, and give the students the header file to implement (which will involve `#include`-ing it).

Comment: You could try with `g++ -flto -Wall -Wconversion *.cpp -o gra`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: `-flto` will apply link-time optimization (as you know), which simply attempts to inline methods after they've been linked from different compilation units. However, it doesn't magically give the linker the ability to distinguish between different return types (since that information has already been stripped out by the compiler).

Comment: You are wrong: I got once a warning about type incompatibility wih `-flto` (both at compile and link time) of some global function or variable on some old version of OCaml!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of compiling the student's code separately, why don't you just include it directly in your tester program?

```
int x(int);
#include <stu.cpp>
```

Then you should get a nice error like this:

```
a.cpp:2:8: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
```

While this is not the "normal" way to compile a student's code, it guarantees that the code can be checked.

---

Alternatively, you may use a compiler command-line option like `-include` (GCC, Clang) to force the compiler to include a header file containing your desired API when compiling the student's C++ file. As an example:

**api.h**

```
int x(int);
```

compile with `g++ stu.cpp -include api.h`, and the appropriate error will be raised.

Comment: It can lead to false positives though, such as symbol redefinition.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Why? The first solution transcludes `stu.cpp`, so `stu.cpp` wouldn't be independently compiled. The second solution only injects a header of the grader's choice, which should contain only function prototypes. I don't see where symbol redefinition errors would occur?

Comment: There was another answer, now deleted, using function pointers that was pretty elegant, especially since it would also make it easy to check when a student flat out skipped defining a method. With this approach, is there a way to raise an error if the method was never defined? I am concerned that "just try calling it" won't always work since C++ will automagically convert lots of types behind the scenes.

Comment: It is also hard to check between functions that have parameter types that convert to one another (long instead of int, esp if they are the same size on that platform)

Comment: In general, if both source files define static variables/functions with the same name, they'll cause a compilation error if both are brought into a single compilation unit.

Comment: @daveagp: The person who posted that answer noted that it did not actually answer the question, because it still required stu.cpp to have the right header.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I see. If this was a concern, I would think that the second solution would solve it (since in that case you still have two separate compilation units, as expected).

Comment: @daveagp: If the method wasn't defined, either approach will simply error out with an undefined symbol error. ("just try calling it" doesn't work if what you're trying to call doesn't exist; type conversion has nothing to do with that).

Comment: @soandos: if the return types aren't *the same* (modulo typedefs), the compiler is obligated to throw an error. If `int` and `long` aren't the exact same type (and they shouldn't be), then `int foo(); long foo();` throws an error.

Comment: @nneonneo and constructor type parameter differences?

Comment: @soandos: if you declare `int foo(int)` but define `int foo(long)` then you will get a link error because the types differ.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
// this is gra.cpp
#include "stu.h"
#include "stu.cpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << x(0); // test their code
}
```

And compile only `gra.cpp` of course.